# Is there any way to replace break to exit a for loop early?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for oPosition in dots:
    if ((oPosition.cx - 8) < mx < (oPosition.cx + 8)) and ((oPosition.cy - 8) < my < (oPosition.cy + 8)):
        draging = True
        break
```

This is the code I want to use in my program, but the teacher told use that we are not allowed to use `break` or `continue`. Is there any way in Python to replace this and stop the loop?

Comment: If you want to exit the loop early, you have to use `break`; is there any context for *why* you aren't allowed to use `break`?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the way to eliminate `break` + boolean is by dumping the code into a function and returning the result. But Python offers a builtin for this, [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), which accepts an iterable and returns `True` if at least one of the items in the iterable evaluates to truthy:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Dot = namedtuple("Dot", "cx cy")
dots = [Dot(1, 2)]
mx = 3
my = 3

dragging = any(((x.cx - 8) < mx < (x.cx + 8)) and ((x.cy - 8) < my < (x.cy + 8)) for x in dots)

print(dragging)
```

The definition of `any` is basically:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

Logically, you are using a loop to test whether **any** of the elements of `dots` satisfies this condition. The sensible way to do this in Python is using the `any` function:

```py
draging = any(
    dot.cx - 8 < mx < dot.cx + 8 and dot.cy - 8 < my < dot.cy + 8
    for dot in dots
)
```

Note that the brackets in your condition were unnecessary because `+` and `-` have higher precedence than `<`, which has higher precedence than `and`.

Of course, if your teacher doesn't want you to use `break` then maybe they don't want you to use `any` either. In that case, the solution your teacher expects is probably something like this:

```py
draging = False
for dot in dots:
    if dot.cx - 8 < mx < dot.cx + 8 and dot.cy - 8 < my < dot.cy + 8:
        draging = True
```

This is basically the same as your original code, just without `break`. It still gives the correct answer; the loop never changes `draging` back to `False` after finding a dot satisfying the condition. This meets your teacher's requirements, but it is worse because it doesn't stop early when the result is already known to be `True`.

It is possible, but not straightforward, to write a loop in Python without `break` which will stop early after finding a match: you need to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop.

```py
draging = False
i = 0
while i < len(dots) and not draging:
    dot = dots[i]
    if dot.cx - 8 < mx < dot.cx + 8 and dot.cy - 8 < my < dot.cy + 8:
        draging = True
    i += 1
```

I'm assuming here that `dots` is a list. Again, this is worse code than what you wrote in the first place, but it meets your teacher's requirements.